# Save FTP files in JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json, ftp

I'm trying to make an array of all my ftp files. I thought that would be easy. However, I want to have an array like this:

```
files = [
  "index.html":"_content from index.html_"
  "somedir/things/server.txt":"_content from server.txt_"
  "process/server.php":"_content from process.php_"
]
```

Is there any way to do this?

After I have this, I would like to put this array in a JSON file, that doesn't seem so hard. However, then I have things like images, which can't be saved in a JSON file right? So, I want them to download to my hard drive. How do I do that?

Thanks in advance...

#### UPDATE 1

This is what I just found:

```
<?php 
$ftp_server = "ftp.example.com"; 
$conn_id = ftp_connect ($ftp_server) 
or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server"); 

$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, "user", "pass"); 
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) 
die("FTP Connection Failed"); 

ftp_sync (".");    // Use "." if you are in the current directory 
ftp_close($conn_id);  

// ftp_sync - Copy directory and file structure 
function ftp_sync ($dir) { 

global $conn_id; 

if ($dir != ".") { 
    if (ftp_chdir($conn_id, $dir) == false) { 
        echo ("Change Dir Failed: $dir<BR>\r\n"); 
        return; 
    } 
    if (!(is_dir($dir))) 
        mkdir($dir); 
    chdir ($dir); 
} 

$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, "."); 
foreach ($contents as $file) { 

    if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') 
        continue; 

    if (@ftp_chdir($conn_id, $file)) { 
        ftp_chdir ($conn_id, ".."); 
        ftp_sync ($file); 
    } 
    else 
        ftp_get($conn_id, $file, $file, FTP_BINARY); 
} 

ftp_chdir ($conn_id, ".."); 
chdir (".."); 

} 
?>
```

I want to do something like this, but instead of getting the whole file, I want to get the path to the file and the content and save them in an array.

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you mean by "all my FTP files" - where are these files? Do you mean "All files in a given directory"?

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't understand your question. I did meant all files in a given directory!

Comment: Sounds like a poor design idea. It's probably better to just get the directory list and then fetch the file contents separately rather then try and encode them into the JSON response.

Comment: Well, my idea is complicated and this seems the most simple solution. by the way I fixed it already.